# Confusing syntax when creating function with generic return type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get more comfortable using generics in TypeScript.

In the example below I understand the majority of what's going on:

Firstly I create a `Person` object type

```
type Person = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
  location: string
}
```

I then create a `getUsers` function which accepts 2 generics, `T` and `K`.

```
const getUsers = <T extends Person, K extends keyof T>(users: T[], key: K): T[K][] => {
  users.map(user => console.log(`${user[key]}`));
}
```

`T` extends my `Person` type because I want this to be an object, and `K` extends the keys of `T` because I want the keys index signature from the `Person` object.

I then have two arguments `users` which is an array of `T`, and `key` which will be a key of `T`.

My confusion is here:

`T[K][]`

This looks weird to me because in TypeScript if you want to set a type to be a multi-dimension array you do double brackets `[][]`.

And here `[K][]` this to me looks like nested array, could someone please explain in more detail why the syntax is like this?

I understand it's just saying an array of objects but I only know that because I watched a video using this example, if I saw this without that example I wouldn't have come to that conclusion.

Comment: In the same way that `T[]` means an array of things of type `T`, `T[K][]` means an array of things of type `T[K]`, i.e. accessing the type of the property on `T` corresponding to the key `K` in the same way that `user[key]` is accessing the value. (Note that the compiler rejects your implementation because neither `getUsers` nor the `.map` callback returns anything.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly reading `T[K][]` as something like `T([K][])` when it is actually `(T[K])[]`.  There are a few distinct and not-completely related uses of the square bracket characters (`[` and `]`) in TypeScript's type system:

- `T[]`: if you have a type `T`, then "`T[]`" is a synonym for [`Array<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays).  There's also `readonly T[]` which is a synonym for [`ReadonlyArray<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type)
- `T[K]`: if you have an object-like type `T` and a key-like type `K`, then `T[K]` is the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) representing the type of value you'd get when indexing into an object of type `T` with a key of type `K`.
- `[]`, `[T]`, `[T, U]`, `[T, U, V]`, `[T, U, V, ...W[]]`, `[T, ...A, U]`, `[T, U?]`, `readonly [T, U]`, etc: there are all [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of some form or other.  Some of that syntax has to do involves [optional elements, readonly tuples, and rest elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions), as well as [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types). In particular you should be careful to distinguish between *the empty tuple* `[]` and an array like `T[]`, and to distinguish between *a single-element tuple* `[K]` and an indexed access like `T[K]`.  They look similar (if you ignore what's happening before the opening bracket) but they are not related.
- `{[k]: T}`, `{["x"]: T}`, `{[k: string]: T}`, `{[K in P]: T}`, `{[T in U as K<T>]: V}`, etc.  these all use square brackets to correspond to keylike things inside an object type.  There are important distinctions between *computed property keys* (like `{[k]: T}` and `{["x"]: T}`, [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) (like `{[k: string]: T}`), and [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) (like `{[K in P]: T}` and `{[T in U as K<T>]: V}`).  Hopefully these aren't as easy to confuse with the others, since they are surrounded by curly braces.

---

Anyway, `T[K][]` is equivalent to `Array<T[K]>`, which means: the type of an array  whose elements are of type you get when reading a property from type `T` with a key of type `K`.  In your example code, the call signature `{<T extends Person, K extends keyof T>(users: T[], key: K): T[K][]}` means a function which accepts a `users` array of some subtype `T` of `Person`, as well as a key `key` of a type `K` known to be a key of `T`, and which returns an array of values corresponding to the `key`-keyed property of the elements of the `users` array.  Indeed, just by that signature, it would be a plausible guess that the implementation of such a call signature would be `return users.map(user => user[key])`, which works:

```
const getUsers = <T extends Person, K extends keyof T>(
    users: T[], key: K
): T[K][] => users.map(user => user[key]); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBQKlQEMBbCALikWHgEtUBzAGn0OMcqIFdSAjBK0JQANsgDGxYHTRUa9JrgC+uXOLQ0onYAFVECRJigAeACpQIAD2ARUAE0NwkaZlADSF67YdQA1hBBkADMoUwA+AAo2Am59JCpTAG0AXVd-ECo3XABKBMS3ZJTMMKhYgwA6UmIwCLL4YtK4xPTk7NwgA)